# When does SQL Server choose an index scan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
select 
    a.Transport_Mode, sum(a.Inv_Qty)
from 
    dbo.DespSum_Year a, dbo.Item_Master b
where 
    a.Inv_Date between '2011-04-01' and '2012-03-31'
    and a.item_name = b.itemcode
group by 
    a.Transport_Mode
```

I have 10 million rows in `despsum_year` and a non-clustered index on `Inv_date`.

When I am running the above query it shows its using a table scan. Can anyone tell me how to make the query using index scan?

Comment: schema? We have no clue what is in what table.

Comment: Table Scan indicates is a **heap** - there's no clustered index. Fix that **first**. Then you need to be sure to have an index on both `inv_date` as well as `item_name` and `itemcode` - and possibly even `transport_mode`.

Comment: @marc_s : The OP hid it very well, but this is a join... `from DespSum_Year , Item_Master`, so we need more details on each table.

Comment: Without your table structures (column names and datatypes) and knowing what indices all together you have, we cannot really help....

Comment: And I would recommend to **always** use proper ANSI SQL join syntax - don't just enumerate tables separated by a comma! Use `..... FROM dbo.DespSum_Year d INNER JOIN dbo.Item_Master i ON d.item_name = i.itemcode .....`

Comment: Others have told you a bit, something to get clear, you can set things up so the query engine will use an index scan, because it's the best choice. It's in charge though, most times you can't make it, and it's a bad idea to do so. Some changes to your schema will render the choice a poorer one.

Comment: For clear understanding I have edited my post. As @marc_s suggestion I have created index for DespSum_Year on (inv_Date,transport_mode,item_name). But Still Query engine is using Table scan. Also I have tried forcing query engine using my newly created index which takes much more time then usual. any suggestion pls

Comment: @SathyaNarayanan - Updated my answer.  Your results from your covering index imply that the `JOIN` filter is most important than the `BETWEEN` filter.  Try any of the indexes I mention in my answer, but where you have `item_name` earlier in the index than `inv_date`.

Comment: @SathyaNarayanan: if the table is relatively small, the query optimizer might just decide its cheaper to just scan the whole table - which is **especially** true if it's a heap (no clustered index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three parts to your query that require a sorted table.
1. The `JOIN`
2. The `WHERE` clause
3. The `GROUP BY`

Your query isn't using the index because the others have been deemed more important.  Put indexes on the other fields, and composite indexes where appropriate.

I would give more details, but unfortunately your query doesn't say which field belongs to which table.  Please give the ***full*** details of each table's schema and indexes for more details.

Also, knowing a bit more data behaviour would be nice: Will gouping by Transport_Mode give a few large groups or many small ones?  Is item_name/itemcode a unique key in one table?  etc, etc.

**EDIT**

Thanks for adding the tables to the fields in your query.  It's still pretty limiting without knowing more about the data, but I'll try to help you.

***1).*** You don't use the `Item_Master` in your `SELECT` or `GROUP BY`

This means that you're either using it as either a filter (1:0..1), or multiplier (1:1..many), or both (1:0..many).

I'll assume you use it as a filter.

***2).*** You use `BETWEEN` to filter `Inv_Date`

I'll assume `Inv_Date` is a DATETIME and has no time part; it's always midnight - to represent dates only.  Giving 366 dates in you case *(leap year)*.

Together these mean that you have a table which you want to filter by two columns and group by a third.  You need to determine which order those fields should be sorted in to give the least amount of effort to give your final result.

There are 6 possibilities...

```
1). Transport_Mode => Item_Name      => Inv_Date  
2). Transport_Mode => Inv_Date       => Item_Name  
3). Item_Name      => Transport_Mode => Inv_Date  
4). Item_Name      => Inv_Date       => Transport_Mode  
5). Inv_Date       => Transport_Mode => Item_Name  
6). Inv_Date       => Item_Name      => Transport_Mode
```

If you have `Transport_Mode` first, it's very friendly to your `GROUP BY`.  Every possible mode will be pre-grouped together ready for aggregating without sorting.  Then, for each group you just need to filter the records, with a `JOIN` to filter `Item_Name` and a `BETWEEN` to filter `Inv_Date`.

So, a covering index on `(Transport_Mode, Item_Name, Inv_Date)` seems good to me.

But that's partly because you have 366 values of `Inv_Date` that your query covers.  If you were only interested in one day, it would be better to have `(Inv_Date, Transport_Mode, Item_Name)`

But if you have very few values in `Transport_Mode` and many, many values in `Item_Name`, maybe you would benefit from having `Item_Name` before `Transport_Mode` in your index?

Without more details on your data, I would recommend creating all 6 indexes, filling your table up to represent a real life situation (if it isn't already), and then running your query.  When you check the execution plan you can see which index the optimiser prefers.

Or create one at a time and profile the query as it uses different indexes and execution plans.  You can then keep the one(s) that are most useful to you across all of your queries, rather than just one.

***BUT***, in all cases, make sure you index `itemcode` on the `Item_Master` table as well!

Comment: Very Excellent and detailed answer given for my understanding. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors. You can try to force use your index with query hints and compare execution plans (especially estimated row count and cost for Primary Key Lookups). What is selectivity for date condition? In general for this query (really it depends on data structure, but just as an assumption) index on (item_name, Transport_Mode) will work better.

Comment: The OP hid it very well, but this is a join... `from DespSum_Year , Item_Master`